# correct way to customize rwd theme ce 1.9

Tags: theme, magento-1.9, rwd, rwd-theme

I want to edit some of the theme files without changing the default, but the files of the **design/frontend/default/default** folder is not overriding this theme. I also tried to create the folder **design/frontend/default/rwd** but not resolved.

Is there a way to replace only some files. In the latter case, I'm thinking of duplicating the theme and change the call in the admin panel.

Comment: Ok.. I read this here ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide) and I am confused to say the least. Why do I need Compass and Sass and all that stuff?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you haven't seen it already, check out http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide.

The guide has additional information you'll need to get started.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to Customize RWD theme.in your rwd package you can make a new theme like

`design/frontend/rwd/yourtheme` and start copying the files which you want to customize in yourtheme.

copy files from `design/frontend/rwd/default` to `design/frontend/rwd/yourtheme` and start customization.

Comment: Not sure why you would use this method instead of the theme fallback structure added in 1.9 (other than you didn't know about the new method). Custom themes that reside within a default package is one of my pet peeves.

Comment: @pspahn, so is it advisable to use `custom package & custom theme` OR make custom theme in existing `rwd` package OR `custom package and default theme` ?

Comment: create custom theme in the rwd package and work accordingly on the customization

Comment: and how about creating custom package and making `rwd/default `as parent theme in theme.xml ? Do we need to copy css and js too ?

Comment: Don't just create a new theme inside the rwd package. Create a new custom package with a default theme (and any others you may want, ie for multisite). You don't need to copy over assets to your custom package as `theme.xml` will get the files from the rwd package if they don't exist in your custom package.