# Is there any issue if I am using Magento RWD theme as it for my shopping website?

Tags: rwd

Is there any issue if I am using Magento RWD theme as it for my shopping website

Comment: Possible duplicate of [correct way to customize rwd theme ce 1.9](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24730/correct-way-to-customize-rwd-theme-ce-1-9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There have no issue with use of RWD theme* .You can use magento rwd theme

**it is  very good to use rwd theme of latest magento ce version 1.9.2.2**

**Because of**

---

- ***`It is made by magento itself`***
- ***`Have follow magento coding standard`***
- ***`Design is responsive`***

### Update:

As Sander say, As `Magento RWD  is follow osl3 license agreement`.So there are `no legal issue with this`

Comment: I just want to confirm there is any LEGAL action against us If i am using Madison Island as it is for my Shopping Website

Comment: @AzmatUlhaq no there is not, it's published under OSL3 which allows you to use it.